# Merging data from 3 pie charts into 1 pie chart

Tags: google-sheets, charts, merge, pie-chart

please help with this issue! I'm in desperate need. As you can see in the below link, I have 3 pie charts for October, November, December - how can I merge the info from these 3 charts to collate into 1 summary pie chart?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_eSR50QFFzWiP1YK1vb_VCx4cpXgZPJ9p1PJqFh-XiE/edit#gid=0

HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find my answer
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U0sGonQrZkasDkGIR5NGPJkkMk7SDCYNAcoiaU_gv1s/copy

I see that pie charts use only top 5 of MOST used things.
To combine 3 months you need to sum all the data for all months and get TOP5 of the sum.
I use query function for this:

```
=query({B2:C6;F2:G6;J2:K6},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc limit 5 label sum(Col2) ''",0)
```

You need to repeat this for each top5 set.

Then you make a new pie chart based on combined data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is based on just 1 site, I have 12 other sites whose data is on separate sheets, is there a way of combining all 13 into 1 report without merging the sheets?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. You only need to combine more ranges into query. Look at {B2:C6;F2:G6;J2:K6} - it takes 3 separate ranges and stack one over another. You can stack more and these ranges can be in different sheets. But they need to have the same number of columns. You can stack for example {Sheet1B2:C6;Differentsheet!X5:Y100;Onemoresheet!H5:I22} . Curly brackets mean that you build a table. Semicolon between ranges mean that you put one range on top of another. If you find my answers useful, please click an arrow at the top of my answer and give me points :-)